# I can not import openzeppelin, but get error 'File import callback not supported'

Tags: openzeppelin, solc, compiler, import

I get 'File import callback not supported' when I try to compile my simple solidity contract, that imports ERC721. Can anybody help?

Here is what I have already done:

I have installed openzeppelin in my project folder:

[image: install openzeppelin]

This is the solidity contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Mycoin is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("MyCoin", "MYCO") {} 
}
```

This is my compile script:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const solc = require("solc");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const coinPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "mycoin.sol");
const src = fs.readFileSync(coinPath, 'utf8');

const input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    "mycoin.sol": {
      content: src,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
console.log(output)

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in output.contracts["mycoin.sol"]) {
  fs.outputJSONSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract + ".json"),
    output.contracts["mycoin.sol"][contract]
  );
}
```

I'm using VSC, and the editor indicates that it can see the openzeppelin file. But apparently the compiler can not find the openzeppelin file. Because I get an error (file import callback not supported) when I run the compile script:

[image: file import callback not supported]

I would like to make this project without Truffle/Hardhat, if it is possible.

Comment: Does this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321111/file-import-callback-not-supported ?

Comment: Take a look at [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) if you don't like Truffle/ Hardhat.

Answer (score 1):

Take a Look at [@Julissa DC](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/80107/julissa-dc)
 answer.

**Alternate Solution -**

Instead of importing Openzeppelin from package. You can directly paste code from github and import it.

Your code will look like

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ERC721.sol";
import "./IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "./IERC721Metadata.sol";
import "./Address.sol";
import "./Context.sol";
import "./Strings.sol";
import "./ERC165.sol";


contract Mycoin is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("MyCoin", "MYCO") {} 
}
```

And Your Root Directory should look like

├── Mycoin.sol

├── [`ERC721.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol)

├── [`IERC721Receiver.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol)

├── [`IERC721Metadata.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol)

├── [`Address.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Address.sol)

├── [`Context.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Context.sol)

├── [`Strings.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol)
├── [`ERC165.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165.sol)

├── [`IERC165.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC165.sol)

Include all above files in you project in root directory, or in any directory you are confortable with. Like wise edit import path of files.

NOTE - Change import statements in Files according to path

i.e. `import "./extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol";` to `import "./IERC721Metadata.sol";`